# Python join sequential rows

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

An example of my data:

```
name  day        text    
john  1 october  hello
john  1 october  world
mary  1 october  good friend
john  1 october  python is cool
peter 1 october  love is
peter 1 october  in the air
```

I want to join "text" when the column "name" and "day" is the same in sequential rows. "day" is not always "1 october" and the dataset is very large. This is what I want:

```
name  day        text
john  1 october  hello world
mary  1 october  good friend
john  1 october  python is cool
peter 1 october  love is in the air
```

Here is my code:

```
data = data.fillna(' ')
data = data.groupby(['name', 'day'], as_index=False).agg({'text': ' '.join})
```

What I am obtaining but it is not what I want:

```
name  day        text
john  1 october  hello world python is cool
mary  1 october  good friend
peter 1 october  love is in the air
```

How I should change my code?

Comment: This means that there is another column that specifies a certain order. I assume this is the index?

Comment: Dude if you want to get the data then some other column would also be in the condition, because as per your requirement it is giving you the correct output

Comment: Yes, the order is the index. But the index is not always the same value so I cannot use it in the groupby

Answer (score 1):

Craft a custom grouper with [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html), [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
group = df[['name', 'day']].ne(df[['name', 'day']].shift()).any(axis=1).cumsum()

df.groupby(['name', 'day', group], as_index=False).agg({'text': ' '.join})
```

Output:

```
    name        day                text
0   john  1 october         hello world
1   john  1 october      python is cool
2   mary  1 october         good friend
3  peter  1 october  love is in the air
```

Answer (score 0):

**Dataframe to start with**

Let's suppose we have the following dataframe :

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ["john" ,  "john",  "mary", "john",  "peter",  "peter"], 
                    'day': ["1 october", "1 october", "1 october", "1 october", "1 october", "1 october"], 
                    'text': ["hello", "world", "good friend", "python is cool", "love is",  "in the air"],
                    })

print(df)
#     name        day            text
# 0   john  1 october           hello
# 1   john  1 october           world
# 2   mary  1 october     good friend
# 3   john  1 october  python is cool
# 4  peter  1 october         love is
# 5  peter  1 october      in the air
```

**Proposed script**

In the following we use a boolean mask and `cumsum` Pandas function as a trick :

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ["john" ,  "john",  "mary", "john",  "peter",  "peter"], 
                    'day': ["1 october", "1 october", "1 october", "1 october", "1 october", "1 october"], 
                    'text': ["hello", "world", "good friend", "python is cool", "love is",  "in the air"],
                    })

m1 = df['name']!=df['name'].shift() # e in pos N != e in pos N+1
m2 = df['name']!=df['name'].shift(-1) # e in pos N != e in pos N-1
df['Fusion'] = (m1 & m2).cumsum()

df = ( df.groupby(['name', 'day', 'Fusion'], as_index=False)
         .agg({'text':lambda x : ' '.join(x.astype(str))})
         .drop('Fusion', axis=1)
         )

print(df)
```

**Result**

```py
    name        day                text
0   john  1 october         hello world
1   john  1 october      python is cool
2   mary  1 october         good friend
3  peter  1 october  love is in the air
```

**Observation**

What does intermediary step `df['Fusion']` looks like ?

```
    name        day            text  Fusion
0   john  1 october           hello       0
1   john  1 october           world       0
2   mary  1 october     good friend       1
3   john  1 october  python is cool       2
4  peter  1 october         love is       2
5  peter  1 october      in the air       2
```

`Fusion` content is increased by `cumsum` each time it encounters boolean `True`